# Looking for cleats to match my vintage Mavic pedals

Tags: pedals, clipless, cleat

Which type of current cleat would match these vintage Mavic pedals (Mavic 646 LMS SSC I believe)?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't think those are the 646, but the cleat you probably still want to use is the Look Delta cleat. Go to a bike shop and try the delta cleat in there.

In the olden days, everyone was rebadging Look cleats as their own. 
The 646 (and many old pedals) use [Look Delta cleats](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20150321060450/http://www.bikepro.com/arch_products/pedals/amavic_pedal.shtml) (aka the original/traditional/ARC Look cleat; NOT the Keo cleat). The 646 should use the black cleat since it has float adjustment on it.

Picture of the Delta cleat (From [REI](https://www.rei.com/product/610474/look-delta-road-cleats)):

[image]